# SAS/ACCESS & client encoding for Greenplum (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, odbc, sas, greenplum

am trying to find a way to instruct ODBC drivers - Datadirect ODBC to use win1251 for client session.

There are for ways mentioned in USer Guide:

1. Using the \encoding command in psql, which allows you to change client encoding on the fly.
2. Using SET client_encoding TO: => SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'value';
3. Using the PGCLIENTENCODING environment variable.
4. Setting the configuration parameter client_encoding in the postgresql.conf file

But as far as i understand options 1 and 3 in not suitable for ODBC drivers, option 2 I am also could not use - because i use SAS and this engine doesn't allow me to execute manually edited SQL's - it use a lot of automatic codegeneration.

I have tried option client_encoding in postgresql.conf file, moreover I have tired to execute follow clommand in psql admin session: `alter user sasuser SET client_encoding to WIN1251;` but nothing changes - by default client encoding is still `UTF8`...

currently in Datadirect ODBC.ini file i have follow string:

```
IANAAppCodePage=2251
```

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Found tht problem is in the SAS/ACCESS for greenplim - when we use SQL pass-through then encoding sets to win1251, but when we use LIBNAME for access the same datasource form the same user account, and from the same environment in the SAS encoding swithing to UTF8. For some reason SAS/ACCESS for greenplum send eplicit command to Greenplum: `set client_encoding to utf8` and thet is the the root of the problem. 
Unfortunately - we didn't find a way how to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should definitely do the trick:

```
ALTER USER sasuser SET client_encoding TO WIN1251;
```

Only remaining explanations can be:

- You are in fact connecting to the DB with a different user.
- At some point during the connection `client_encoding` is explicitly set to another value.
- You are connecting to the wrong database cluster (same IP? same port?)

To find out, set [`log_statements = all`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT), make the server cluster reload, start a session with your user-unfriendly tool, and check the database log, if and what was actually communicated to the server.
Don't forget to reset `log_statements` or your log files will grow huge.

---

<strike>Or it is all just a **typo** in `Datadirect ODBC.ini`:</strike>

```
IANAAppCodePage=2251
```

That supposed to be 1251?

Nope. `IANAAppCodePage MIBenum 2251` stands for "WINDOWS_1251". That's not it.

Comment: I see in log files that my client send command `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8'` an the initialisation stage... Question is - how to configure my client (SAS via ODBC) to not issue this command...

Comment: @YuryKochubeev: have you checked the typo thing? .. Actually, that should be correct. 2251 --> WINDOWS_1251.

Comment: @YuryKochubeev: Then you need to find out, where this setting comes from. I cannot help with Datadirect ODBC itself.